# Get Server DateTime In Silverlight application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have `silverlight` application. When using `DateTime.Now` it gives me the `client datetime`. In this way the client can change his time on whatever he wants. I want to be sure that datetime comes from server. What I want is to give me the `server` datetime. Any ideas how this can be accomplish ?

Comment: What do you mean by _client_ and _server_ here? `DateTime.Now` returns local time of the machine that runs.

Comment: Indeed - your Silverlight application is running on a client... what server are you talking about? (If it's the server the application was originally downloaded from, I suspect there's no guarantee that that server even still exists...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get datetime in silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858469/how-to-get-datetime-in-silverlight)

Comment: You can get server time from WCF service.

Comment: One simple question to ask. The client call the url where the silverlight application exists. Then the application (silverlight project dll) goes to client. If the silverlight make call to web service it goes to server where the service lives ? So DateTime and other references dll to the web service take information from the machine where the service lives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a call to the web service or an api to get a server DateTime.  On the server if you use `DateTime.Now` it will give you the datetime of the server time zone.  You can also use `DateTime.UtcNow` to get Universal Time.